# Unable to use UseDatabaseNullSemantics / UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior with Entity Framework in join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and would like to set UseDatabaseNullSemantics to true  for a query (for performance reasons).  However, whether UseDatabaseNullSemantics is true or false, the query always performs the null check in the join condition.  I do see that the behavior is correctly changed if the comparison is in the where clause, but not when the condition is in the join condition.

For example, suppose I have a table, T1, with a nullable ID, NullableId, and I try the following:

```
(context as System.Data.Entity.DbContext).Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true; -- or false

var q = 
  from x in context.T1
  join y in context.T1 on x.NullableId equals y.NullableId
  select x;
var results = q.ToList();
```

Whether UseDatabaseNullSemantics is set to true or false, I see the same query generated, something like:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[NullableId] AS [NullableId]
    FROM  [dbo].[T1] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[T1] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[NullableId] = [Extent2].[NullableId]) OR (([Extent1].[NullableId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[NullableId] IS NULL))
```

So, I am not quite sure how to disable the null comparison check in the join condition.

This is with Entity Framework 6.1.3.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: As an aside (which I didn't want to include in the answer), this is what frustrates me the most about using LINQ to generate SQL: LINQ is based on C# semantics which *do not* always translate to good or correct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think that Entity Framework is doing the "right thing" based on the C# semantics of the LINQ expression.

You expressed `x.NullableId equals y.NullableId` for the join. But since Entity Framework recognizes both columns as nullable (presumably they're "optional" in your model?), it must compare in SQL using both the value equality operator and checking if both are null.

Consider a situation where both `x.NullableId` and `y.NullableId` are null: per the LINQ expression these rows would match since they're "equal" in terms of C# equality semantics even though they're not equal in terms of standard SQL nullability semantics.